# How to find out which unique index constraint was violated?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a container with a couple unique keys. When I try to create a record that violates these constraints, I get a generic error that doesn't specify which key is the problematic one. Is there any way for me to get this info without having to query back and try to figure it out manually?

I'm running Cosmos/NoSQL (docker emulator, WSL2).

The error:

```
Create document failed
Message: {"Errors":["Unique index constraint violation."]}
```

Comment: how are you inserting record?

Comment: Tried using the nodejs API and also the included explorer web interface that ships with the emulator, I get the exact same error message on both

Answer (score 0):

One way to view the **unique keys** defined for your container is to view the ARM template for your Cosmos DB resource. To view the ARM template for your Cosmos DB resource, follow the below steps:

1. Go to the Azure portal and navigate to your **Cosmos DB** account.

[image]

2. Click on `Export Template` under the `Automation` section. This will generate the ARM template.

[image]

3. Click "Download" to download the template file.

[image]

4. Open the downloaded template file in a text editor.
5. Search for the **uniqueKeyPolicy** label to find the unique keys defined for your container.

This will give you a quick and easy way to view the unique keys defined for your container.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very useful information. Unfortunately, I wanted to know specifically which key was violated when the API returned the error. Let's say a user is trying to create a record that has two unique fields, like `email` and `username`. I'd like to know which key was violated so I can tell them that instead of having to query back to find out which of them are duplicated.

Comment: It is not possible to find which key is violated without any code.